# The rank of the characteristic polynomial of a $\lambda$-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, matrix-rank, characteristic-polynomial

Assume $F(\lambda, y) = \mathrm{det}(yI - V)$, where $V = (V_{ij}(\lambda))_{4\times 4}$ and each $V_{ij}(\lambda)$ is a polynomial of $\lambda$.

If $F(\lambda, y) = 0$ always has four different roots $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ except a finite number $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_g$.

Prove
$$\mathrm{rank}(yI - V) = 3$$
under constraint $F(\lambda, y) = 0$ and $\lambda\neq \lambda_j, j=1,\dots,g$.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: What is the rank of a polynomial? What is $y$? a number? The $|\cdots|$ bars denote determinants?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry, I have edited the question.

Comment: Better now :-) What does «Assume $F(\lambda, y) = \mathrm{det}(yI - V) = 0$», your first sentence mean?  The «$=0$» part seems to not want to be there.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you, I have re-edited the question. I want to know the rank of $(yI - V)$ under constraint $F(\lambda, y) = 0$.

Comment: @user1551 Sorry, I didn't describe the problem clearly. I have re-edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is to discard the other possible ranks by using the Rank-Nullity Theorem.

Comment: Thank you.  Below is my solution.  

Assume that $F(\lambda, y)  = 0$ has four different roots $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$ for $\lambda\notin\{\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_g\}$. One can diagonalize $V$ as $\widetilde V 
 = \mathrm{diag}(y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4)$. Then $\mathrm{rank}(y_iI - \widetilde V) = 3$ for $i=1,2,,3,4$.

Comment: Yes, that's a lot nicer than my argument. My argument was that if the rank is less than 3 then the kernel has dimension at least two, and that gives a repeated eigenvalue; that discards ranks $0,1,2$. And rank $4$ is not possible for otherwise $F(\lambda,y)\ne0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.